# Token retrieval failed with an error In Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication, azure-data-studio

Using the latest Azure Data Studio Version: 1.32.0

Attempting to access a database using `Azure Active Directory MFA` and am getting the error:

> Token retrieval failed with an error. Open developer tools to view the error

How can I resolve?

```
Connection type: Microsoft SQL Server
Authentication type: Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA support
```

---

The server, account, and database fields are all populated with their respective necessary information.

A browser window pops up asking for username/password, which I enter valid credentials for, followed by the authentication being confirmed in the browser that follows, accompanied by instructions to close the browser window. Azure Data Studio then has the error displayed as mentioned above.

Comment: Is your local computer time NTP synced? There are also the nuclear options, deleting your ADS Azure Accounts folder, as presented in [issue 12165](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/12165).

Comment: Yes @AlwaysLearning, this computer is domain joined and time synced using NTP

Answer (score 35):

Problem seems to be with a cached token.
try to delete the token from here **C:\Users{UserNameHere}\AppData\Roaming\azuredatastudio\Azure Accounts** and try to re authenticate.

Comment: the path on mac is :  `~/Library/Application Support/azuredatastudio/Azure Accounts` . Remove the file `azureTokenCache_azure_publicCloudin`

Comment: on linux (i tried this on a debian based distro): `~/.config/azuredatastudio/Azure Accounts/azureTokenCache_azure_publicCloud`

Comment: Azure Data Studio needs to be restarted after the deletion of the cache file for the changes to take effect. With this addendum, works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I had to delete both cache files to get this to work - ```azureTokenCache_azure_publicCloud``` and ```azureTokenCacheMsal-azure_publicCloud```

Answer (score 8):

You have cached stale credentials.

Select the credentials in the `Accounts` section, then delete them and add fresh credentials.

[image: Azure Data Studio Accounts Section]

Comment: @TillyJonesy it's an alternate answer, not fix all for every problem. Your comment adds no value to either this answer, the other answers, or even the one you choose.

Answer (score 4):

If you open the Command Palette - `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` on Windows - one of the options is `Azure Accounts: Clear Azure Accounts Token Cache`. After applying this you'll be prompted to reload ADS.

You should then be invited to refresh your account credentials when you attempt to create a connection. If you're not, run `Azure: Refresh All Accounts` from the Command Palette and try creating the connection again.

**Explanation**

As mentioned by @JayakrishnaGunnam-MT in their answer, the problem seems to be to do with cached tokens. Running the first command deletes `azureTokenCache_azure_publicCloud` and `azureTokenCacheMsal-azure_publicCloud` from `C:\Users\{UserNameHere}\AppData\Roaming\azuredatastudio\Azure Accounts` without you needing to do it manually.

Comment: Update: There's a GitHub issue for this bug in ADS v1.45.1 and 1.46.1 - https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/24340

Comment: `Azure Accounts: Clear Azure Accounts Token Cache` worked for me. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @philipnye This is now working on ADS 1.47.1

Comment: @cddt I'm still experiencing serious connection problems on 1.47.1, albeit possibly with a different Connection Error (`Error: Failed to get Azure account token for connection`).

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS user, please find `/Users/{your_username}/Library/Application Support/azuredatastudio/Azure Account` and remove it.

There is sometimes bug even download latest version but can't work, so I would recommend remove `azuredatastudio` for sure.